# Forwarding request made to my server to another server on the same path

Tags: proxy, http, apache2, proxypass, forwarding

I need to create a sub-directory mapping in the Apache server such that each request made to the path `/another-path` gets forwarded to `https://some-website/another-path`. How could I do this?

If the incoming request is on my server `https://my-website/another-path`. I want it forward to another server on `https://some-website/another-path`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Where is the exception? All requests should be proxy forwarded to the same backend, so `ProxyPass` directive is your solution. But what is the difference between the incoming request of `/another-path` and `https://my-website/another-path`. Are that different vhosts?

Comment: @TRW What I want is this. A request `https://example.com/this-path` gets forwarded to `https://example-1.com/`.

Comment: @TRW Any help?.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393706/how-to-use-a-different-path-name-in-proxypass-than-the-tomcat-context-name which is nearly the same problem but with Tomcat.

```
ProxyPass /this-pass/ https://example-1.com/
ProxyPassReverse /this-pass/ https://example-1.com/
```

Use `ProxyPass`. The problem is not the domain, the problem is the different location on the backend server. `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` can handle that. If it isn't working out of the box, then try ´Rewrite` hack on the response.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /this-pass/ [R]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /this-pass/$1 [P]
```

But I think, this isn't necessary (I didn't test that rewrite).

Comment: Could you help me understand your answer?

Comment: Maybe you need to update your question about - what do you need to understand? Do you know, how Apache works? Do you have access to the Apache configuration? What is your current configuration? I could explain, how reverse proxing works, but I'm not sure what you don't understand. When you know, how Apache2 config works and you can change it, did you try to use ProxyPass and tested it? What was the result? That would help me to improve the answer.